# Looks like it may

Tags: word-usage

Is it incorrect to use "looks like" followed by "may"? Example:

> Looks like you may have to do that.
>       Looks like it may rain.

Instead of:

> Looks like you have to do that.
>       Looks like it will rain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem in using a "may" in this position.

Your examples are grammatically correct and idiomatic.

The style is quite casaul. In formal writing you would not use this kind of expression. A more formal alternative could be:

> It appears likely to rain.  (or similar)

Answer (score -2):

The sentences ARE idiomatic, but ARE NOT grammatically correct.

The word **may** is used to indicate the uncertainty of a future event. "It looks like it **may** rain," indicates that the clouds are there, but we are not certain if they will produce rain. **Might** can also be used the same way.

Beginning the sentence with **looks** is shorthand, but the grammatically correct way to write, or say, the sentence is to begin with **it**. **It** is the subject, and is the indicator of the logic for the rest of the sentence.

Shorthand is fine for speaking, but use the more formal language when writing.

Comment: There is a difference between "informal" and "ungrammatical" or "incorrect". Leaving out pronouns that can be inferred from the context happens a lot in English.